# Set the starting and ending rows of a range in Excel 2010 based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm making a price calculator for my print shop, because it takes a long time to quote jobs if you don't know all of our materials and prices.

[I've uploaded a screenshot of the calculator here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEoIS.png). It's still very much a work in progress, but I'm pretty certain it needs 3 sections:

- **Section 1:** Choose the material, laminate, and cutting options from drop down lists.
- **Section 2:** Input the dimensions and quantities to get a unit price and subtotal.
- **Section 3:** Check boxes for any optional charges, which modify the unit prices and subtotals in section 2.

What I'd like to be able to do is split the router charge in section 3 across only the materials that are being routed, which means I need the total quantity of routed material.

As of now, the only way I can see to do this is to define a range of cells in J6:J38 starting at the first row where the word "Route" is encountered in G6:G38 and ending at the first row in C6:C38 where a value that is not "–" is encountered. Am I right, and is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: If instead you enter "Route" on each applicable line you could use a straightforward `SUMIF()`

Comment: The reason I don't want to do that is because there may be times when the user would need to choose route 10 or more times for a single estimate.

Comment: What you're asking is not clear. In your example, "Route" seems to only appear in Column G, but your suggested procedure looks in columns C through G? Also unclear, is "Route" applied to all sublines of Rigid PVC, or just the line it is actually on?